# Checking the continuity and differentiability of function.

Tags: derivatives, continuity

Ok someone didn't like my post because I ask questions of a homework. I send it again with more precisions, I have problem solving this so please don't be hateful :)

I have an homework that says:

$f(x)=\begin{cases} x^2-3, &x<1\\ -2, &x=1\\ \sqrt{x-1}-2, &x>1\end{cases}
$

It asks me if $f$ is continuous on $1$ and if it is differentiable in $1$.
I learned that a function is continuous when we can draw it without raising our hand, ok, but when it's just in one point (here $f(1) = -2$) I really don't know what to do.

If someone can help me it would be really nice, thanks! :)

Comment: actually the right procedure when a question is closed is to edit the previous question to include what you have attempted.  the question will then go through a review process to decide if it should be reopened.  hmm... sounds like an imprecise definition of "continuous" you might want to include your background and what do you understand by "differentiable". your post was closed not because anyone hates you but on this site, homework is expected to come along with attempt, thoughts, telling us where do you get stuck and some volunteer might get you unstuck. it is not a homework solving site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you can see easily that $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=1$ because $f(1)=-2$ and $$\lim_{x\to 1^-}f(x)=\lim_{x\to 1^+}f(x)=-2$$

A function $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=c$ if it is defined at $x=c$ and $\lim_{x\to c}=f(c)$

Now we differentiate the function in each piece. If the result is continuous then the function is differentiable

$f'(x)=\begin{cases} 2x, &x<1\\ 0, &x=1\\ \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{x-1}}, &x>1\end{cases}$

we have

$$\lim_{x\to 1^-}f'(x)=2;\;\lim_{x\to 1^+}f'(x)=+\infty$$
the limit doesn't even exist! So the function is not differentiable at $x=1$.

Bonus

The derivative which tends to $+\infty$ has an interesting geometric meaning. It means that the tangent to the graph of the function is vertical at that point.
As you can see in the picture below, the  graph has two tangents at point $(1,\;-2)$, which means it is not differentiable, indeed.

Hope this is useful

$$...$$

[image]

Comment: Excuse me ? You said the limit doesn't even exist, but what is these 
 : limx→1−f′(x)=2;limx→1+f′(x)=+∞ I'm really confused :/

Comment: Yes, indeed. If a limit exists then it is unique. If right limit and left limit are different then the limit does not exist

Comment: Okay, your answer was really helpful, thank you :D Just one more question, how did you "draw" that graph since the function isn't the same after x = 1 ? Did you use Geogebra ?

Comment: @Antoine Yes geogebra with command *Curve* to change the expression from an interval to another
 https://wiki.geogebra.org/en/Curve_Command

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to solve your question
 completely.

I will just help you by giving hints, and you will be able to solve on your own.

You just said that a function is continuous if we can draw it without lifting the pain. So, if $f(1)=-2$, then what do you think should be the value of function just before $1$, for instance at $x=0.999999999$ and what should be it's value just after $1$, e.g. at $x=1.0000000001$?

Let's first discuss continuity then we will discuss differentiability.

Comment: I'd say that if the function is continuous, f(0.99999) = something like -2.0000001 and f(1.00000001) = something like -1.9999999

Comment: I see that x^2 - 3 = -2 for x = 1, so they are both same function, but (x-1)^(1/2) - 2 is not the same :/

Comment: @Antoine Doesn't need to be the same function! The value of the limit must be the same, and it is so, actually: $(1-1)^{1/2}-2=-2$ and this is enough to say it is continuous

Comment: @Antoine You said that $\sqrt{x-1}-2$ isn't tending to $-2$ as $x$ tends to $1$. Why so? Actually it is.